# What does the `WM` in `WM_INPUT` and `WM_MOUSE` stand for in VC++?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++

I want to know what does the `WM` stand for in Windows C++ programming?
It is full of `WMxxx` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different type of messages in Windows such as Command Message, Window Message, Control Message etc. WM stands for Window Message.

[Check this for more details:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)